# What scope does ":my $foo" have and what is it used for?

Tags: raku

With a regex, token or rule, its possible to define a variable like so;

```
token directive {
    :my $foo = "in command";
    <command> <subject> <value>?
}
```

There is nothing about it in the language documentation [here](http://docs.perl6.org/language/grammars), and very little in [S05 - Regexes and Rules](https://design.perl6.org/S05.html), to quote;

*Any grammar regex is really just a kind of method, and you may declare variables in such a routine using a colon followed by any scope declarator parsed by the Perl 6 grammar, including my, our, state, and constant. (As quasi declarators, temp and let are also recognized.) A single statement (up through a terminating semicolon or line-final closing brace) is parsed as normal Perl 6 code:*

```
token prove-nondeterministic-parsing {
    :my $threshold = rand;
    'maybe' \s+ <it($threshold)>
}
```

I get that regexen within grammars are very similar to methods in classes; I get that you can start a block anywhere within a rule and if parsing successfully gets to that point, the block will be executed - but I don't understand what on earth this thing is for.

Can someone clearly define what it's scope is; explain what need it fulfills and give the typical use case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## What scope does `:my $foo;` have?

`:my $foo ...;` has the [lexical scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scoping) of the rule/token/regex in which it appears.

(And `:my $*foo ...;` -- note the extra `*` signifying a dynamic variable -- has both the lexical and [dynamic scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Dynamic_scoping) of the rule/token/regex in which it appears.)

## What this is used for

Here's what happens *without* this construct:

```
regex scope-too-small {    # Opening `{` opens a regex lexical scope.
    { my $foo = / bar / }  # Block with its own inner lexical scope.
    $foo                   # ERROR: Variable '$foo' is not declared
}

grammar scope-too-large {  # Opening `{` opens lexical scope for gramamr.
    my $foo = / bar / ;
    regex r1   { ... }     # `$foo` is recognized inside `r1`...
    ...
    regex r999 { ... }     # ...but also inside r999
}
```

So the `: ... ;` syntax is used to get exactly the desired scope -- neither too broad nor too narrow.

## Typical use cases

This feature is typically used in large or complex grammars to avoid lax scoping (which breeds bugs).

For a suitable example of precise *lexical only scoping* see the declaration and use of `@extra_tweaks` in [`token babble` as defined in a current snapshot of Rakudo's Grammar.nqp source code](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/c76d9324a9f67e4075683e38a63a9788161c17cc/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp#L117).

P6 supports [action objects](https://docs.perl6.org/language/grammars#Action_Objects). These are classes with methods corresponding one-to-one with the rules in a grammar. Whenever a rule matches, it calls its corresponding action method. [Dynamic variables](http://doc.perl6.org/routine/is%20dynamic) provide precisely the right scoping for declaring variables that are scoped to the block (method, rule, etc.) they're declared in both lexically and dynamically -- which latter means they're available in the corresponding action method too. For an example of this, see [the declaration of `@*nibbles` in Rakudo's Grammar module](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/c76d9324a9f67e4075683e38a63a9788161c17cc/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp#L5083) and [its use in Rakudo's Actions module](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/dc4ed746ddeb562688985a41e9a51380d7bc0cf6/src/Perl6/Actions.nqp#L9514).